# If I pull an electrical permit for my home in FL can I hire a licensed journeyman electrician to do part of the work?

Tags: electrical, permitting

If I pull my own electrical permit for adding a subpanel and 2 circuits in my Escambia County, FL home, can I hire a licensed journeyman electrician to do all or part of the work with me?  He cannot pull his own permit and his master electrician will charge me double the permit fee to let him pull it under the master's license.

Comment: Most jurisdictions allow you to DIY electrical on a house you both own and live in.  So yeah, you'd be pulling the permit as a DIY job, and officially an electrician wouldn't be involved at all.  Just be careful... with the housing boom (partly caused by COVID), anybody competent is pretty busy, and that leaves the *bottom* of the barrel...

Comment: I don't see any problem with hiring an licensed electrician just because you pulled the permit. But there a lot of local rules and regs that may vary. You should call your AHJ and ask.  How much of the work are you planning on doing yourself? Do you have electrical skills? In many places you don't need a licensed electrician to drill holes and "pull rope" (run the cables) as long it's done according to code. Again, local codes and regs apply, your mileage may vary.

Comment: When I built out my laundry/powder room (which entailed some re-wiring of the main breaker panel), I used a Master Electrician friend to pull the permit (County requirement).  Then me and him worked on it together over the course of a couple of afternoons.  Then he called for the inspection.  He just charged me his going hourly rate for his time on site.

Answer (score 1):

With you pulling the permit you are the responsible party for the work.
Hiring someone on the side is really common. I may have done this for many years myself :).
it’s not only the masters license needed to do work ( in my state general signing supervisor) but you also require a contractors license and this requires bonding. All those costs are why we charge so much.

My current apprentice I believe may be doing some work on the side for friends the same as you are doing I don’t know.

A sub for us is a very simple job, is it legal?
Only if blood related mother, father, brother, sister some states go out to grand parents, grandchildren aunts and uncles other than that no it’s not legal.

When the job is inspected usually the inspector will really look it over making sure it is done right for a homeowner. When I moved to my current location that I had not worked and pulled permits on my home I did it as a homeowner and on the inspection the inspector wanted that were not code required done and was not going to sign off until I grabbed a code book and he asked if I was licensed
After finding out I was he put his X on the paperwork.
When signed off by an electrician they look it over and test GFCI’s as that is a requirement in my state. knowing this the inspector may want more than is required by the homeowner.

Guys that work on the side for $ can be at either end of the spectrum but simple jobs like a sub should be easy for any journeyman and something my first year apprentice could do. today only very close friends get me but a young journeyman wanting some extra $ is quite normal just like a mechanic friend that works on the side.

Answer (score 0):

Not legally. By law you are hiring him as an unlicensed contractor. You are violating Florida laws requiring contractors you hire to be licensed. You will be informed of those laws when you apply for an Escambia County [Electrical Permit](https://myescambia.com/docs/default-source/documents/building-services/permitting-forms/electrical-permit-application.pdf?sfvrsn=2b011d6c_2). Where you check the box claiming to be owner they are required to give you the Florida [Owner/Builder Disclosure](https://myescambia.com/sites/myescambia.com/files/BID_OwnerBuilderDisclosure_0.pdf) Form. Where it says "License" Florida Statutes make it clear it is referring to contractors license.

That disclosure also includes scary statements like "Florida Department
of Professional Regulation may seek civil penalty of no less than $500 and no more than $5,000 for each unlicensed contractor and to the person that hires the unlicensed contractor" and "I, as an owner-builder,may be held liable and subjected to serious financial risk for any injuries sustained by an unlicensed person or his or her employees while working on my property. My homeowner's insurance may not provide coverage for those injuries. I am willfully acting as an owner-builder and am aware of the limits of my insurance coverage for injuries to workers on my property."

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about here in Florida but in Georgia a residential homeowner can pull a Homeowners Permit. I worked as an electrician for 36 years there and did multiple jobs for homeowners over the years like this.